# Ordenar de mayor a menor

Tags: java

```
public void ordenar() {
     for(int i=0;i<vec.length;i++){
         for(int z=1;z<vec.length-i;z++){
             if(vec[z-1]>vec[z]){
                 int mayor=vec[z-1];
                 vec[z-1]=vec[z];
                 vec[z]=mayor;//sale error porque tengo el vector como char, lo cambio a int pero el .toCharArray me sale error.
             }
             System.out.print("| "+vec[z]);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: qieres entender lo que hace el metodo burbuja?? o simplemente qieres oredenar el arreglo vec??

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a S.O. en español. Te invito a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), además, puedes hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y ganar tu primera medalla. En tu pregunta no queda claro el error que dices que te arroja. Entiendo que quieres aplicar el método de la burbuja, pero donde dices *sale error porque tengo el vector como char, lo cambio a int pero el .toCharArray me sale error* no logro entenderlo, ya que no veo como construyes tu vector. ¿Podrías subir tu código completo? Saludos

Comment: Quiero ordenar el arreglo vec

Comment: Para próximas preguntas, añade en tu pregunta la traza de error, los datos con los que pruebas y el resultado esperado. Siempre puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/246457/edit) la pregunta usando el enlace bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas.

Answer (score 1):

Este algoritmo es una solucion a lo que deseas realizar

```
public void ordenarNumeros(){
    List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<>();
    numeros.add(1);
    numeros.add(29);
    numeros.add(-3);
    numeros.add(8);
    numeros.add(17);

    // Ordenando los numeros.
    numeros.stream()
           .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
           .forEach(System.out::println);

}
```

Comment: Tal vez el usuario tenga que aprender a ordenar por si mismo ;). Hay que tener cuidado con eso. Igual, el error que marco en su pregunta es otra cosa.

Answer (score 0):

Este es un algorimo de ordenación

```
 int[] array = {10, 9, 8, 100, 20,1, 2};

       boolean hayCambios = false;

       int auxiliar = 0;

       do{
           hayCambios = false;
         for(int i = 0 ; i<array.length-1; i++){
             if(array[i+1] > array[i]){
                 auxiliar = array[i];
                 array[i] = array[i+1];
                 array[i+1] = auxiliar;
                 hayCambios=true;
             }
         }  

       }while(hayCambios);

       for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i]+", ");
       }
```

Espero que te sirva.